Spotify-qt will list all songs, but will not play them
I need some help! I have an iMac running Ubuntu. I want to listen to Spotify, so I installed Spotify-QT, connected it to my Spotify (which worked, showing me all playlists), and then compiled and installed librespot.
Unfortunately, librespot was in /home/$username/.cargo/bin - and Spotify-QT would not accept this as a path to librespot. I therefore cp the librespot binary to /home/$username/target/release/. Now the client starts, and Spotify-QT is happy.
However, when I try to play a song, I get an error message: "Failed to resume playback: Player command failed: No active device found". When I check the Spotify-QT settings, it says the client is running. When I check the Spotify-QT logs, I find three error messages:
This happens first and is in the Spotify log: [13:11:19] [err] /home/pikewerfer/target/release/librespot: error while loading shared libraries: libasound.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Then this happens: [13:11:26] [err] Request failed: Error transferring https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play - server replied: Not Found
Then this: [13:11:26] [err] me/player/play failed: Player command failed: No active device found
When I do sudo apt-get install libasound2, Ubuntu tells me I already have the latest package. I am stuck - what else could I do to solve this? Is the first error even connected to the other two?

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

OK, modified the question. I do not believe this is in any way related to Ubuntu at all, but to Spotify-QT and librespot.
